# How do we get name of child nodes of root or any node using Android code?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

From the following code, I am able to get the number of children of the root node but I also want to get the name of them. How could I get it? And what should I make the change in the following code?

```
package com.example.application_for_curd;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        printChildrenCount(rootRef);
    }


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public void printChildrenCount(DatabaseReference ref) {
        ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    long childrenCount = task.getResult().getChildrenCount();
                    Log.d(TAG, "childrenCount: " + childrenCount);
                    for (int i=0;i<childrenCount;i++)
                    {
//                        Log.d(TAG, "childrenName: " + childrenname); // need to involve code here to get children name
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t93jG.png) that exists in a previous question of yours, to get the name of the children that exist within your root node, please use the following lines of code:

```
public void printChildrenCount(DatabaseReference ref) {
    ref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                long childrenCount = task.getResult().getChildrenCount();
                Log.d(TAG, "childrenCount: " + childrenCount);
                for (DataSnapshot child : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                    String childName = child.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "childName: " + childName);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And call this method using:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
printChildrenCount(rootRef);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Company
GodDepartments
students
```

Things to notice, to be able to get the name of the children, which are actually the key of the nodes, you need to loop through the "DataSnapshot" object using a call to ".getChildren()" method.

To get the name of the children under "students" ref, for example, kick it of with:

```
DatabaseReference studentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students");
printChildrenCount(studentsRef);
```